NoSuchMethodError: Class 'Foo' has no instance method 'copyWith'. ( Extension method called on untyped variable)
Will this code compile ?
class Foo {
  
}
extension on Foo {
  int copyWith(){
    return 1;
  }
}

getFoo() {
  return Foo();
}
void main() {
  final foo = getFoo();
  final un = foo.copyWith();
  print(un);
}

If you said yes, you're correct. This code compiles. No issue. And it seems OK too. It will print 1. Right ?
But no,

NoSuchMethodError: Class 'Foo' has no instance method 'copyWith'.

How to fix it ?
Change
getFoo() { to int getFoo() {
Yes, it's crazy how an optional return type annotation can cause runtime errors. It will be desastreous if you work with nuclear code or medical software.
Is this is a bug with Dart ? If not, how to mitigate this ? Any linter or analysis option that enforce  .

Best option: A hope that Dart team will make this a built-compiler error ?

Medium option: A linter option prohibit function call on untyped variable

Worse option: A linter option enforce return type as errors



Dart have a few cases, like missing types on return types and parameters when defining method, where dynamic are inserted implicit. This can, as you show, give some trouble but changing this is rather breaking, So for now, I highly recommend adding the following options to your analysis_options.yaml to make the analyzer more strict about those cases: https://dart.dev/tools/analysis#enabling-additional-type-checks

The Dart analyzer works correctly in this case. The reason there is no compile-time error is that the default type of function declarations is dynamic.
// has a return type of "dynamic"
funcOne() {
  return 1;
}

// has a return type of "int"
int funcTwo() {
  return 1;
}

Unlike the Object type that is used as the parent of all other types in Dart, dynamic essentially "disables" type checking and static analysis and allows you to call any methods on the values of that type. This is the reason why the copyWith call on the foo variable does not raise a compile error but fails in the runtime since copyWith does NOT exist for the dynamic type.
To fix this issue, you need to either appropriately declare the return type of the getFoo() function to be of type Foo or typecast the foo variable to its correct type using the as keyword:
// ...

Foo getFoo() {
  return Foo();
}

// OR

getFoo() {
  return Foo();
}

void main() {
  final foo = getFoo() as Foo;
}


Correctly declaring return types of functions is the expected way to deal with runtime type errors.
The specific rules that can help prevent these kinds of issues:

always_declare_return_types to always declare the return type of functions;
avoid_dynamic_calls to avoid penalties associated with usage of the dynamic type;
avoid_annotating_with_dynamic to avoid using the dynamic keyword in function return type declarations.

New linter rules can be added in the root analysis_options.yaml file following the Dart documentation page on static analysis. You also can explore community-driven linter rule sets, such as very_good_analysis.
